# How to register Android push notification in PHP server?

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I'm new to Android and I want to learn about push notifications in Android. Can anyone please help me out with good tutorial? I'm using PHP in my website.

Comment: Hi Harish. Unfortunately, questions this broad aren't generally thought to be a good fit here. You may get some suggestions in the comments, but a search engine is the best place to start. Have you found anything so far?

Comment: yes, but i'm unable to understand

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with below examples :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

https://gist.github.com/siriusdely/2572588

Sample:

```
<?php
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxxxxxx';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'A push notification has been sent!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck_file_name.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'body' => $message,
        'action-loc-key' => 'Bango App',
    ),
    'badge' => 2,
    'sound' => 'oven.caf',
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```